# I cannot vertically align my login form in React Native

Tags: react-native, layout, flexbox, styles

I simply cannot vertically align my login form in the screen.

I am using nativebase.

Starting with React Native docs example, I have tried many different solutions provided on SO and on other platforms.

This is my login form. I removed unnecessary parts.

```
<Container>
 <Content>
  <Form style={formStyle}>
   <Item>
    <Icon />
    <Input label="email" />
   </Item>
   <Item>
    <Icon />
    <Input label="password" />
   </Item>
   <Button>
    <Text>Login</Text>
   </Button>
  </Form>
 </Content>
</Container>
```

And here is my formStyle

```
formStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
  }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve and how does it look like at the moment?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `alignItems` in your style:

```
formStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
}
```